# Implementing a List template using a Pair template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement a singly linked list template class using my own pair class.  I'm doing this as an exercise to refresh my C++ skills, so that is why I'm not just using the STL.

My List template is parametrized by a single type:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    Pair<T, Pair<???>* >* _head;
};
```

The problem is that I want _head to be a pair whose second element is a pair of that same type.  The idea was the _head.first is the element and _head.second is a pointer to the remainder of the list or NULL if it is the last element.

Is there a way to use a templated type that refers to itself?

Comment: Think about it. Can you have a box that contains itself?

Comment: Were you trying to create a compile time list? or runtime list?

Comment: Kerek SB: You cannot have a box that contains itself, but you can have a box that contains a different box of the same type.  That is what I am trying to model.

Comment: @Dave Linked lists do not contain nodes, they contain linked lists.

Comment: @Dave: No, you cannot, because that gives you an infinite nesting of boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you were trying to do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    Pair<T, ListList<T> >* _head;
};
```

Comment: I guess it should be `Pair<T, LinkedList<T> *> _head` then, but this looks sensible.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I was guessing that the OP was intending that an empty list was represented by _head being null.

Answer (score 0):

The typical singly linked list consists of *nodes*, and each node contains a pointer to the  next node or a null pointer to signal the end:

```
template <typename T> List
{
    struct Node
    {
        Node * next;
        T value;
    };

    Node * head;

    List() : head(NULL) { }

    // ... insert, delete, find, iterate ...
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I was trying to do except that I want use a Pair template rather than defining a Node struct.  Your solution will definitely work, but I am curious if my idea can be made to work as well.

Comment: @Dave: No, because you're attempting to define an infinitely recursive structure. Your idea is *literally* identical to `struct X { X x; };`

Comment: @hyde: Sorry, you're right -- I thought that the specification of the template arguments would be a recursion problem, but given that you only want a *pointer* to the pair, it actually shouldn't be. After all, you could say `Pair<T, void*>` and cast the pointer later, and that would be OK.

Comment: @hyde: So, I think you just need to alternate two nested classes, like in Vaughn's answer: `struct Node { Pair<T, Node *> head; };`. Then it's almost identical to my code, only that you put the two data members into a pair.